# Upload images and video to a tab (not the wall) on a business page?

Tags: facebook, video, upload

We have a facebook page with a numbers of different tabs on it. On one of the tabs we'd like to allow those who've liked the page to upload videos and images. The uploads would only appear on this specific tab.  How is this normally achieved? Can we even use facebook or do we need to plug-in youtube or vimeo etc?

Is there an app or do we need to create one?

Any pointers t all would be much appreciated as we have no idea. Can't seem to find an answer on the forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user selects your Page Tab, you will received the signed_request parameter with one additional parameter, page. This parameter contains a JSON object with an id (the page id of the current page), admin (if the user is a admin of the page), and liked (if the user has liked the page).
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

You can upload a video to a page using the Graph API, see the following Blog post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/515/#video_upload

Comment: Gary, if you find an answer useful you should up-vote it for other user to surface it easily.

Comment: I tried Alexandre but I need 15 reputation before I can do that. Just logged in today for the first time.